# Is fast enumeration considered bad form or is it generally accepted?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, fast-enumeration

Just wondering, it seems like it works pretty well but I want to make sure I am using generally accepted coding practices and not get into bad habits.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's good form. It was introduced as the preferred style of enumeration in Objective-C 2.0, in fact. Use it wherever possible.

Comment: It should also be noted that fast enumeration executes faster than using NSEnumerator, and way faster than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Fast enumeration is a recent addition to the language, so don't be concerned that you're not seeing it much in other people's code.  It takes a while for people to adopt new habits.